# Google Place API, REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: android, google-places-api

Lots of Google Place api REQUEST_DENIED post on Stackoverflow but no answer for me.

1. I have create a project on Google API console
2. Under that project, using SHA1 certificate fingerprint (debug.keystore) and package name to generate the Android API key
3. Already turn on the "Place API" service on Googel API console.
4. The request URL is come from google sample [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) and already replace the generated android API key
   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

But still get the REQUEST_DENIED.......

Comment: You have replaced the key in the URL haven't you?

Comment: Yes, Key for Android apps (with certificates)
API key: 
AIzaSyBgtuprISnWCnMw126CXuyGwA5KgvalObk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Request URL like this.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=API_KEY

I am sure it will work if you configured Google place API correct. Use your API Key.

> How to get API Key.

[image]

Comment: Still {
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Comment: @andrewwang1TW what URL you are trying and make sure you have replaced key=AddYourOwnKeyHere with you Key like i gave example above..

Comment: Yes, I have replace with my API key as https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBgtuprISnWCnMw126CXuyGwA5KgvalObk";

Comment: @andrewwang1TW Make sure your API key is right. I guess your API key is not correct i think something problem in that.

Comment: I use the SH1 comes from keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore and my app package name to generate the API key

Comment: @andrewwang1TW I have uploaded a image where you will get the idea to how to get key API KEY. You will need to use that key..

Comment: I do not understand what u mean, I press the "Create new android key" button under that project to generate the API key

Comment: @andrewwang1TW Go on google Apis then there you will find API access. there you will get key.

Comment: yes I create the key from the screen u post, I press the "Create new android key..." to create the API key...

Comment: here is my API key "Key for Android apps (with certificates)
API key: 
AIzaSyBgtuprISnWCnMw126CXuyGwA5KgvalObk"

Comment: @andrewwang1TW When you created the KEY.

Comment: @andrewwang1TW Create new one and click on Create new browser key.

Comment: use "create new browser key" is OK. Now I got the result from Goolge Place API. Really THANKS. But it's really strange, it's an android app. Can you tell me why? THANKS...

Comment: Thanks, but so far I do not have enough reputation(15 ) to make it the answer. BTW thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem.You should open the 'Places API'service in API console,and then the  result will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If your keyApi is a android key won't work because you need to create another browser api (leave in black for all access allowed) and mixing both on your project. The reason is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224080/request-denied-with-google-places-api-browser-key-or-app-key)

Answer (score 0):

**To use the Places API, you must include an API key with all API requests and you must enable billing on each of your projects.**

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing